# Redux reducer - on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I want to save the current state of a specific reducer into session storage without explicitly calling it on every action.

```
const { handleActions } = require("redux-actions");

// How do i make this logic run on any state change without adding it to every action?
const onStateChange = (state) => sessionStorage.save(keys.myReducer, state);

const myReducer = handleActions
({
     [Actions.action1]: (state, action) => (
         update(state, {
             prop1: {$set: action.payload},
         })
     ),
     [Actions.action2]: (state, action) => (
         update(state, {
             prop2: {$set: action.payload},
         })
     )
 },
 //****************INITIAL STATE***********************
 {
     prop1: [],
     prop2: []
 }
);
```

Is there a way to catch the state change event for a specific reducer?

I know of `store.subscribe`, but that's for the entire store, i'm talking about listening to a specific reducer change

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried libraries like [redux-localstorage](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage) or [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)? Or are you addressing a niche use case that these libraries do not address?

Comment: @excalliburbd - persisting the state is not the only logic i want to run on state change so unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't watch specific parts of your store because your store is actually an only reducer (combineReducers return a single big reducer). That said you can manually check if your reducer has changed by doing state part comparison.

```
let previousMyReducer = store.getState().myReducer;
store.subscribe(() => {
  const { myReducer } = store.getState();
  if (previousMyReducer !== myReducer) {
    // store myReducer to sessionStorage here
    previousMyReducer = myReducer;
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure such a comparison by reference is valid? do reducers' reference change (and only change) if any value changes?

Comment: Yes, it is the main advantage of the immutability of reducers, when the reducer don't intercept the action the same reference of state is returned

Answer (score 0):

You can use [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) to listen for specific actions and persist the store (and do your other logice) when they are fired. This seems like a good fit for your needs.

It's not exactly tied to specific store changes, but rather to a set of actions. However, I think this model (listening for actions, as opposed to state changes) is better suited to the redux design.

The nice thing is you don't have to change any code outside of the saga. I've used this one for autosaving form data and it worked great.

Here's an example of setting up a saga to persist on a few redux-form actions; note that it's not limited to persisting - you can do whatever you want during a saga.

```
function* autosaveSaga(apiClient) {
  yield throttle(500,
  reduxFormActionTypes.CHANGE,
    saveFormValues,
    apiClient);

  yield takeLatest(
    reduxFormActionTypes.ARRAY_PUSH,
    saveFormValues,
    apiClient);

  yield takeLatest(
    reduxFormActionTypes.ARRAY_POP,
    saveFormValues,
    apiClient);
 }
```

If you want to listen to all action types, or do custom filtering of which actions fire your persistence code, you can pass a pattern, or a matching function to takeLatest:

```
   yield takeLatest(
    '*',
    saveFormValues,
    apiClient);
```

More on what you can pass to `take`, `takeLatest` etc can be found [in the docs for `take`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takepattern).

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid.. (writing the same lines on every action)

Comment: My example isn't optimal. Updated to note that you can use a pattern or match all actions.